# How to check the upstream url in git?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-remote

How can I determine the upstream url I configured for my branch in my new project?

I started the new project like this:

1. I cloned a git repo which is a boilerplate.
2. I opened a new repo in github.
3. Made some changes in the local cloned repo.
4. Pushed the newly changes for the first time to the new github repo from the step above. I used the command `git remote add origin https://github.com/..../react-UI.git` then `git push --set-upstream origin main` or the short `git push -u origin main` to configure the upstream url.

Now if I use the command `git remote show origin` it shows me the url of the repo I cloned from.

However, when I navigate in the project directory to `./git/` and use `cat ./config` It displays:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/....../react-boilerplate.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/origin/main
[branch "main"]
        remote = https://github.com/...../react-UI.git
        merge = refs/heads/main
```

Is there a git command to find out the upstream url of the new branch in the new repo? (`https://github.com/...../react-UI.git`).

For future projects where I might use the boilerplate again from my github repo, should I follow the same instructions? (steps 1-4 above)

Please note that in both repos I use the "`main`" branch.

Comment: The `remote = <raw URL>` entry is the extremely ancient (pre-2006 or so) way of doing things. The right thing to do is to correct the URL for `origin` and use `remote = origin`.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is just `git config --get branch.main.remote`

The way you did steps 1-4 seems to have worked, but the way I usually do steps 1-4 would be to delete the .git folder and create a new repo. That works unless you need to keep history, but the history would still be in the boilerplate repo anyways.